# SQL Integrity Error While adding a multiple values to a table in Flask App

Tags: python, mysql

I am creating a Flask App using MYSQL Database. The code seems legit from tutorial and online search I am following but the "Create user function didn't work properly. The error always comes back with missing user_id value although I am adding it. Help me through this I am stuck with over 5 days with this error

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#database connection 
class friends(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    user_name = db.Column(db.String)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    email = db.Column(db.String)
    gender = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self, user_id, user_name, age, email,gender):
        self.id = user_id
        self.name = user_name
        self.age = age
        self.email = email
        self.gender = gender

#route
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        add_usr_id = request.form['new_usr_id']
        add_usr_name = request.form['new_usr_name']
        add_usr_age = request.form['new_usr_age']
        add_usr_email = request.form['new_usr_email']
        add_usr_gender = request.form['new_usr_gender']
        commit_user = friends(user_id = add_usr_id, user_name = add_usr_name, age = add_usr_age, email = add_usr_email, gender = add_usr_gender)
        db.session.add(commit_user)
        db.session.commit()
        message = "The record was added."
        return render_template('add.html', message=message)
    else:
        return render_template('add.html')

@app.route('/show')
def read():
    show_friend = friends.query.all()
    return render_template('show.html', show_friend = show_friend)
```

This is the full error traceback :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1048, "Column 'user_name' cannot be null")
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (user_name, age, email, gender) VALUES (%(user_name)s, %(age)s, %(email)s, %(gender)s)]
[parameters: {'user_name': None, 'age': '32', 'email': 'dfak@ekfl.com', 'gender': 'male'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

Comment: `add_usr_id` is `None`. You have to figure out why the controller is sending that to the `add` route.

Answer (score 0):

```
>         add_usr_id = request.form['new_usr_id']
```

Add a debug `print` or logging statement there.
It will reveal that `None` was passed in.

Either arrange for a better value to be
presented, or hack in some default value.

Here is one way to default it:

```
        add_usr_id = request.form['new_usr_id'] or 'default_user'
```

Comment: I printed the id value to know whether it passes null or a value and it passed the value I type in the HTML form somehow the value is missing in the controller.